# how to do mysql table partitioning in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, query-performance

I'm working on Rails web-framework which have a mysql table exam_scores with 35 millions of records (which may double in 2 years!). exam_scores table has indexing `index_exam_scores_on_student_id_and_exam_id` . still it takes lots of time to execute queries as it is a huge table!. so I was searching for a solution to deal with this situation.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE exam_scores;

  CREATE TABLE `exam_scores` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `exam_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `marks` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `result` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `index_exam_scores_on_student_id_and_exam_id` (`student_id`,`exam_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3542275 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I want to know how to do table partitioning in mysql as I hope this is the only solution. Is it possible? If yes, how to do this on existing table without data loss and affecting code.

Comment: For what it's worth, MySQL partioning is unlikely to help much with a query performance problem in a 35 million row table.Your table is definitely *large*, but it is not *huge.* Indexing is more likely to solve that kind of problem. Please read this, and pay special attention to the section on query performance.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Comment: So you have unique index on student_id/exam_id. But what are the actual queries (which are slow)? Do they benefit from this index?

Comment: @O.Jones you mean partitioning will not improve query performance ? indexing is there already.

Comment: Partitioning is neither necessary nor sufficient to improve query performance, sorry to say.  Get the indexing right first. Read the article I linked, and please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

`PARTITIONing` rarely helps performance.  To help you, we *must* see the queries that are slow.  *Maybe* some could be helped.

Meanwhile, there are other things that *may* improve performance.

- Do you have billions of students?  You probably you don't need a 4-byte `INT` for `student_id` and `exam_id`.  Picking a smaller datatype, such as the 2-byte `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (range of 0..65535), would shrink the size of the data .  Be sure to be consistent between tables.  Smaller --> more cacheable --> faster.
- Are you using `id` anywhere else?  You can probably get rid of it and instead promote the `UNIQUE` key to `PRIMARY KEY(student_id, exam_id)`.  This would make any queries involving `WHERE student_id = constant` run faster.
- There is a 2-byte datatype `YEAR`.
- Is `created_at` used for anything?  (It smells like something provided by some framework.)